# App Store Connect API last uploaded build version and number

Tags: ios, continuous-integration, app-store-connect, continuous-deployment

I'm setting up CI/CD app deployment to upload builds to TestFlight/AppStore, hence need to check the version of previously uploaded build from App Store Connect before building

I've generated JWT token required for authenticating with App Store Connect API and got app id from: https://api.appstoreconnect.apple.com/v1/apps

And now I'm requesting builds related to that app id using: https://api.appstoreconnect.apple.com/v1/apps/{id}/builds

which gives me this response (response data is paginated (offset/limit) and is not sorted by build version that was uploaded) :-

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "type": "preReleaseVersions",
            "id": "<resource id>",
            "attributes": {
                "version": "1.3",
                "platform": "IOS"
            },
            <some additional trees>
        },
        {
            "type": "preReleaseVersions",
            "id": "<resource id>",
            "attributes": {
                "version": "1.4",
                "platform": "IOS"
            },
            <some additional trees>
        },
        {
            "type": "preReleaseVersions",
            "id": "<resource id>",
            "attributes": {
                "version": "1.2",
                "platform": "IOS"
            },
            <some additional trees>
        },
        <some more data...>
    ],
    "meta": {
        "paging": {
            "total": 55,
            "limit": 50
        }
    }
}
```

What I'm looking for is some query string parameter or different API or approach from which I can get the latest build version without needing to call the API recursively for getting all the uploaded versions and then finding the largest from the array

Comment: Please checkout the official docs: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi There is no way to get the latest build at the moment.

Answer (score 5):

I haven't found a simple way but this is the best I've figured out.

```
https://api.appstoreconnect.apple.com/v1/builds?filter[app]={app_id}&sort=-version&fields[builds]=version&filter[preReleaseVersion.version]={version_num}&limit=1
```

This will return something like the following:

```
{
   "data": [
    {
      "type": "builds",
      "id": "ef87f7e1-20e0-4128-9c4d-7aadb23b23ed",
      "attributes": {
        "version": "30"
      },
      "links": {
        "self": "https://api.appstoreconnect.apple.com/v1/builds/ef87f7e1-20e0-4128-9c4d-7aadb23b23ed"
      }
    }
  ],
  "links": {
    "self": "https://api.appstoreconnect.apple.com/v1/builds?filter%5BpreReleaseVersion.version%5D=1.2.11&limit=1&sort=-version&filter%5Bapp%5D=&fields%5Bbuilds%5D=version",
    "next": "https://api.appstoreconnect.apple.com/v1/builds?cursor=AQ.GXQEGw&filter%5BpreReleaseVersion.version%5D=1.2.11&limit=1&sort=-version&filter%5Bapp%5D=&fields%5Bbuilds%5D=version"
  },
  "meta": {
    "paging": {
      "total": 29,
      "limit": 1
    }
  }
}
```

From here you just grab the "version". It's confusing but in this situation, the version is the build number.

There is one problem with this approach. Sometimes apple won't process a build even though it uploaded. For some reason, those builds don't show up on this request. I don't understand why Apple is being so stubborn about this. I've noticed FastLane is able to get the latest build despite this but I haven't reverse-engineered their process yet.

Answer (score 2):

You can constrain your search by checking for builds uploaded for a particular `preleaseVersion`:

`params = { 'filter[version]' => short_bundle_version }`

`GET https://api.appstoreconnect.apple.com/v1/preReleaseVersions`

This will return you metadata containing urls for builds associated with that version. You can then extract the related build urls:

`json['relationships']['builds']['links']['related']['data']`,

And then request the associated JSON for the url, which will contain the build ID and its `uploadDate`.